# asp.net view pdf in new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, telerik

Here is my code how I upload and open my `PDF` document

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton" runat="server"    
onclick="linkButton_Click">Show PDF</asp:LinkButton>  
   <telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="RadAsyncUpload1" runat="server"   
     MultipleFileSelection="Disabled"  
     MaxFileInputsCount="1" Width="230px">
  </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>

protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        if (RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count != 0)
        {
            byte[] _myfile = null;
            UploadedFile _file = RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles[0];
            _myfile = new byte[_file.InputStream.Length];
            _file.InputStream.Read(_myfile , 0, (int)_file.InputStream.Length);
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _fileItenary.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=sample.pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(_fileItenary);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

This code work correctly and can show my uploaded pdf in browser .
But , pdf file is show in same page (same tab) .
When click my `Show PDF` link , I want to view my pdf in new page (new tab) .
Kindly help me , Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do it on a client side with somethink like this

```
 OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/
```

or

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenWindow()
    {
      window.open('nameofyourpage.aspx','_blank','height=450,width=500,scrollbars=0,location=1,toolbar=0');
    }
  </script>

  OnClientClick="OpenWindow()`enter code here`"/
```

Comment: `enter code here` region is to add all code of `linkButton_Click` ?